# Check if entire array is instanceof

Tags: java, swing, generics

I want a Generic Method, however I'm not sure if it's ideal for this scenario, nor am I very much familiar with how Generic's work (if someone could link me a good tutorial or article, I'd very much appreciate it.)

However, I wanted to create a method that handles initialization of JComponents, and if the array of JComponents was All JRadioButtons, to be sent to a different method.

```
public void initializeComponent(JComponent...components)
{
     if(components[0] instanceof JRadioButton)
         initializeJRadioButtons(components[]);
}
```

However, this will only check whether the first one is a JRadioButton, I feel Generics may handle this better, but is there a way to check if all components are JRadioButtons without looping?

Such as if someone does this.

```
JRadioButton[] radioButtons = new JRadioButton[2];
...
initializeComponent(radioButtons);
```

Comment: Maybe you could make the task easier by looping over components, then do `instanceof` test and delegate to `initializeRadioButton` (no plural) for each component?  Do you need to initialize arrays of components at once? I don't see how generics would help you do that.

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder That won't work.

Comment: may be if all of the entry are not `JRadioButton`

Comment: Any particular reason not to use loops?

Comment: Well it's supposed to handle all JComponents, but if it's specifically a JRadioButton, it'd send it to the specified method, and perhaps in the future a specific method for each one, it's supposed to make initialization from a 3 or 4 step process to a 1 step process @tobias_k

Comment: @Otanan Yes, figured that out now, too. So you have special methods for initilizing radio buttons, and this and that other stuff, but you want this as an entry method for all those? Why? Also, have you tried just overloading? `init(Foo... foos)`, `init(Bar... bars)`, etc.?

Comment: wrong idea, wrong question, wrong answers, please whats goal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't check them without looping over them. Consider any process that would do it for you - at some point it would still have to check them one by one as they're distinct objects.

However, what you could do use use method overloading. You could have a method with the signature of

```
public void initializeComponent(JRadioButton...components)
```

You then know that every one of those components will be a radio button, hence can skip any checking.

You can then have the method you've already got in your question which may have to check each component to do the correct initialisation.

```
public void initializeComponent(JComponent...components)
```

Comment: This is definitely what I might end up using, however, would  List<JRadioButton> radioButtons = new ArrayList<>(components); work? Or would I get an exception thrown for trying to add a non JRadioButton to the list if the components array is holding a non-JRadioButton?

Comment: You'll get a syntax error because you're `components` variable type is not `JRadioButton` or a subtype of it (rather a supertype). It'll fail at compile time.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't think of this!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what the problem of looping over the components is:

```
boolean isRadioButtons = true;
for (Component c : components) {
    if (!(c instanceof JRadioButton)) {
        isRadioButtons = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to check whether the array that is passed is actually a `JRadioButton[]` array or not, you can use the following code. Although this is a hack, that does the job:

```
public static void initializeComponent(JComponent... components) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    // Get the Class instance for an array of type JRadioButton.
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("[Ljavax.swing.JRadioButton;");

    if (clazz.isInstance(components)) { 
        System.out.println(true);
        initializeJRadioButtons((JRadioButton[]) components);
    }
}
```

The method uses the encoding for the `JRadioButton` array to get the `Class` instance for that type of array. See [`Class#forName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29) for more details on this.

If the `components` is an instance of `JRadioButton[]`, then you'll get `true` as result. Remember, this is just a hack, as I already said. IMO, overloading is the best option for you.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a built-in way to check if all entries in an array are of a specific sub type type.

Loop it.